# find if a child node exists using php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have been researching this for a while and can't seem to find the problem with my code.  I am attempting to get the price of an item and this works great if there is a price, but if the price is missing it throws an error.
Here is the code:

```
    /* Amazon Offers ALGORITHM */
$parsed_xml = amazon_xml($isbn);

$current = $parsed_xml->ListMatchingProductsResult->Products->Product;
$asin = $current->Identifiers->MarketplaceASIN->ASIN;

// get information based on the items ASIN
$price_xml = amazonPrice_xml($asin);
    if($price_xml) {
    while(count($lowestPrices) < 2)
    {

        // check to see if there are values
        if(xml_child_exists($parsed_xml, $current->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount))
           { 
            $listPrice = $current->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount;
          } else {
            $listPrice = 0;
          }
        $currentPrice = $price_xml ->GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult->Product->LowestOfferListings->LowestOfferListing;
        print_r($listPrice);
```

My function to check for child nodes is:

```
    function xml_child_exists($xml, $childpath)
{
$result = $parsed_xml->xpath($childpath);
if (count($result)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to check if child node exists

```
function xml_child_exists($xml, $childpath)
 {
  //$result = $parsed_xml->xpath($childpath); $parsed_xml variable?
    $result = $xml->xpath($childpath);
   if (isset($result)) { // changed from count to isset
    return TRUE;
   } else {
    return FALSE;
   }
}
```

Comment: I get this error  PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object  on the line that starts with $result = $parsed_xml

Comment: yeah just noticed that $parsed_xml is not defined anywhere in the function if you change to $xml->xpath, should solve your problem. updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [property_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) 
I'm using it to check duplicated child while adding new child into xml using SimpleXML. It should work for you. If you just pass in the child name, and its parent.

```
function xml_child_exists($xml, $child)
{
 return property_exists($xml, $child);
}
```